# How to add new HTML to dynamically created popover (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3 I am trying to add a new HTML element into a dynamic popover like

```
$(document).on('click', '#send-app', function(){
  console.log("Clicked!");
   $("#result").html('<p>New HTML Element</p>');
});
```

but it is not working! How can I fix this?

```js
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
    html: true, 
    content: function() {
          return $('#popover-content').html();
        }
});

 $(document).on('click', '#send-app', function(){
   console.log("Clicked!");
   $("#result").html('<p>New HTML Element</p>');
  });
```

```css
 .popover {
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div id="wrap">
    <a data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" role="button" data-html="true" href="#" id="login" class="btn btn-default">Send</a>
    <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
        <div class="well well-sm" style="margin-top:16px;  padding-top:14px; padding-bottom:0px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" type="text">
                        <span class="btn input-group-addon" id="send-app">Send</span>
                        </div>
                        <p class="help-block animated"></p>
                    </div>
                <div id="result"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see you are getting the content for the pop over on the existing `#popover-content` element which is currently hidden.

And then when it generates the content for the popover it creates another `#result` element. The problem here is that when you have 2 or more element with the same `id` and use that `id` on the selector it only targets the first element found with that id.

So instead of having an `id` on the element, use `class` instead. And make sure to target only that `class` inside the popover.

e.g.

**HTML**

```
<div class="result"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '#send-app', function() {
  console.log("Clicked!");
  $(".popover .result").html('<p>New HTML Element</p>');
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78s9tmxt/1/)